# Android O heads up notifications

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, heads-up-notifications

I've been rewriting my code to match Android O notification changes and heads up notifications stopped working. I target SDK version 26 and below is my code.

Please help me get heads up notifications working. Any help is appreciated.

```
    public void createNotificationChannel() {
NotificationChannel messagesChannel = new NotificationChannel(MESSAGES_CHANNEL, context.getString(R.string.channel_messages),
            NotificationManagerCompat.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
    messagesChannel.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION),
            new AudioAttributes.Builder().setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION).build());
    messagesChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000});
    messagesChannel.setLightColor(Color.WHITE);
    messagesChannel.setShowBadge(true);
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(messagesChannel);
}
    public void showMessageNotification(final String conversationId, final String message) {
        Intent contentIntent = ConversationDetailsActivity.getLaunchIntent(this, conversationId);
        contentIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(ConversationDetailsActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(contentIntent);

        PendingIntent contentPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(conversationId.hashCode(), FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Notification notification = buildNotification(R.drawable.ic_message_24dp, message, contentPendingIntent);
        notificationManager.notify(conversationId.hashCode(), notification);
    }
    private Notification buildNotification(final int iconResId, final String message, final PendingIntent contentPendingIntent) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, MESSAGES_CHANNEL);
        Notification notification = builder
                .setSmallIcon(iconResId)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.notification_title))
                .setContentText(message)
                .setContentIntent(contentPendingIntent)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .build();
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        return notification;
    }
```

from my build.gradle

```
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xxxxxxxx"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 21
    versionName '1.13'
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Comment: Do you compile sdk 26? Can I see your gradle.build(app)

Comment: @MrAppMachine added build.gradle

Comment: I hope my medium post will help you with proper explanation and code at https://medium.com/@md.noor.asad/heads-up-push-notification-from-rest-and-firebase-when-app-is-in-background-or-foreground-6c4457fb6d4b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I forgot to set sound/vibration for my notification. Heads up only work for notifications with priority >= high that have sound/vibration set.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you created a notification manager. You can learn about how to set up notifications [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)

Hope this helps!

Comment: NotificationManager isn't something you create. I get the instance of it like so: notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE); and use it.

Comment: That's exactly where I got my code from.  It doesn't work